# State of a ViewState

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, viewstate

I have been trying to use a ViewState variable ViewState["username"] assigned in the one of the usercontrol of the page from one other usercontrol of the page.

The value of ViewState seems to be null.

Y cant usercontrols within a page read the ViewState values of eachother.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: ViewState is not a secure place to save a username. Try using Forms Authentication instead.

Comment: ViewState["Username"] = user.Username;  // this is assigned in one control and in the control where i read the viewstate  string username = ViewState["Username"] as string;

Comment: Maybe storing the `ViewState` in `Page` will solve your problem, instead of `UserControl` itself

Comment: I can use session to avoid this confusion... but just curious if the state of a viewstate exists between usercontrol in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This by design - ASP.NET will differentiate between view-state of various (instances of) controls. This differentiation is based on control ID. It is needed because otherwise control author cannot use same view-state key and there is no way of knowing what keys might be used by other control authors.

In your case, I will suggest that you store the data into view-state at page level and pass it to your user controls (from page) via properties.